# Note naming convention while creating scales

Tags: guitar, theory, scales

I am having some trouble with naming notes in a major scale.

The major scale formula is 
0 , 1, 1 , 1/2 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1/2

If I use this formula to calculate notes in G# major scale, I get the notes as:-

G# A# C C# D# F G G#

However I see many sites and apps use the following notes in a G# major scale:-

G# A# B# C# D# E# G G#

This really confuses me.

Why are notes such as B# and E# present.
I even remember seeing some scales which have notes such as Cb and Fb.

Please help me clearing out my note naming concepts.

Thanks,
Rajeev

Comment: my answer below details the rules for ya.  The G# key signature is never used since the number of accidentals are way above the number you'ld need for the equivalent Ab key signature.

Comment: Both examples are inaccurate - scales use consecutive letter names, and neither of these do. Writing music using these notes just will not work. See my answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your formula of half- and whole-steps is correct, but the spelling is not.

Different ways of spelling the same pitch are called **[Enharmonics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enharmonic)**. You already know that all of the "black key" notes on the piano have more than one name, but you can also alter notes further than a semitone, or make an alteration to two "white keys" that are next to one another.

You are already familiar with `b/#` notation: [*accidentals*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accidental_%28music%29) that modify the pitch by a half step, or *semitone*. There are also double-sharp and double-flat accidentals that modify by whole steps, or by two semitones.

The reason for using these is to spell every note in the scale with a distinct letter name, and thus, distinct and orderly placement on the musical staff. With enough accidentals, I could spell the "`G#`" scale as, say...

`G# Bb B# B## Eb E# G G#`

But written out on a staff this would be pretty incomprehensible, especially for someone sightreading.

To solve this problem, we start with every note name on the staff:

`G A B C D E F G`

... and then modify those notes with accidentals to suit the scale in question:

`G# A# B# C# D# E# F## G#`

Now, this is still a lot of symbology on the page, so to simplify, we use **[key signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_signature)** to put all of this information in one place. Double sharps are *almost never* used in key signatures, however, so as others have mentioned, the typical spelling of this scale would be its enharmonic equivalent of Ab major (which only has four flats as opposed to 8 sharps).

Comment: I'd just like to add here that when spelling a scale, *each letter can only be used once.* NReilingh cited one reason for this rule.  Also, enharmonic spellings may show harmonic motion or recontextualization pertinent to the music, so, even though "B#" and "C" and "Dbb" all *sound* the same, they are *very* different notes.  Lastly, "sharp" notes tend to stay in sharp keys and "flat" notes tend to stay in flat keys. Again, it would be hard to read a G# major scale the way NReilingh showed us in his answer.

Comment: Yes. Please NO ONE EVER WRITE THAT :-)

Comment: Haha, some scary things come across my desk...

Answer (score 5):

To provide a very simple answer ,as above are complex. You are aware of the notes which constitute G major. To arrive at G# major, simply # each and every note of G. This will give ## on occasions, so that's correct. Since the formula TTSTTTS works for a major scale, it will work for all of them. HOWEVER, G# is such an impractical key to work in, no-one uses it. Why would they, when Ab contains exactly the same notes when played, but only 4 bs when written.

One could take this to ridiculous ends, and write, for example, in Cb, with loads of flats, but B maj., with 'only' 5 #s, would make life easier, wouldn't it ?

Comment: You can't just # every note of G keysig to get G#'s.  That'll break the rules of spelling scales correctly.

Comment: @StephenHazel What do you mean? This works fine as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @NReilingh well, there are 12 notes you need to spell in each key signature.  G is spelled:

G Ab A Bb B C C# D Eb E F% F 

If you "just sharp them", you get:

G# A A# B B# C# Cx D# E E# F# Fx

Hey, ya know, you're right!  Sorry bout that.
The seperate letter per step and tonic,dominant having their own letter still hold.

I dunno though.  I'm not sure that'd still be the case with all key signatures (just sharping them).  But it is with this one at least.

Comment: @StephenHazel It should always work when you use it in this fashion, because the starting scale is going to have the correct pattern of note names. If you alter each note by the same number of half steps without changing the letter, then you'll still have the same pattern. (For what it's worth, you're the only person I know of who takes into consideration all 12 tones when working with a tonal key signature. You're accurate, but typically the use of chromatic pitches is so contextual that the notes may or may not be related to the key signature as such.)

Comment: @NReilingh I dunno, I'd think that the "dominant HAS to have it's own letter" rule could throw a wrench in that.  

The reason I care about all 12 notes of the keysig is that given a midi file, my program has to draw correct standard notation for it.

Comment: @StephenHazel I don't know that rule... and an augmented 5th or diminished 5th above the root is going to be the same letter as the dominant. You might be able to come up with some reliable shortcuts for simpler music that doesn't stray very far from the key signature, but for most purposes, MIDI and standard notation are not isomorphic.

Comment: @StephenHazel Anyway this is off topic -- we can discuss in chat if you like.

Comment: @NReilingh well, the aug or dim5 wouldn't show up in sheet music on the same line as the 5th.  So it wouldn't be spelled with the letter of the 5th...  Right?  Scale spellings map which line/space the note sits in.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10327/discussion-between-nreilingh-and-stephen-hazel)

Comment: @StephenHazel - There is no can of worms here ! As I stated in my answer, it all works.There are NOT 12 notes you need to spell each key signature, any more than there are 17 notes you need to write a tune - C,C#,Db,D,D#,Eb, etc.A key in Western music contains 7 diatonic notes.                                    To successfully write these notes, EACH has to have its own letter name, thus place on a line or a space. Otherwise it would be nigh on impossible to read. MIDI has its own conventions, but we're talking MUSIC here !

Comment: All the above points to some very good reasons why G# is rarely, if ever, used as a key in its own right. There's nothing going for it. Why would anyone write in G# when Ab is available ?

Comment: Why? I don't know. But it happens: see wikipedia's C-sharp major page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-sharp_major). As for G# major (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-sharp_major): "The final pages of A World Requiem by John Foulds are written in G-sharp major with its correct key signature shown in the vocal score including the Fdouble sharp."

Comment: @Tim scale spelling is also used to place notes on the staff.  Spelling a scale is not too difficult.  The trick comes when there are notes outside the scale used.  There are 5 notes outside the major scale that must be placed on the staff if used.  Standard notation specifies which line/space and whether to #/b/X/bb/% the note.

Comment: @StephenHazel Which particular 5 notes outside the major scale are you referring to ? Any notes which do not appear in a normal scale, such as major anything, will have all 7 notes to play. Any which are # or b will be shown in the key sig. Any other notes not actually in the scale itself will be dealt with by using accidentals- #, b, x, bb or naturals, showing that those particular notes do not in fact belong to the said key.

Comment: @StephenHazel - I think you mean the missing notes from the 12 available. If so, they get put in the appropriate place.E.g. if in Cmaj., there is a note from Fmin.chord, it gets called Ab. However, if the same note belongs to a C+ chord, it'll be called G#.They get put in their proper place, and musicians who are aware of chord structure, etc., will know why they've been called by that particular name, and hung on that particular line or space.

Comment: @NReilingh I can't figure out how to make that chat thing work to save my life (and I'm a computer programmer!)  You can go ahead and chop out my comments if you don't mind.

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to the tricky world of standard notation :)

Scales need to be "spelled" in a very exacting way.
There are also things like double sharps (X) and double flats (bb) to think about.

rules:

- start with spelling of 7 scale tones per keysig's sharp else flat
- 7 tones of scale ALL on DIFFerent letters
- if minor, M6 and M7 are ALWAYS m6,m7 SHARPED (naturaled flat/doublesharped) since "sort of in the scale as almost tones"
- SINGLE LETTER for tonic, dominant - not duped even for tones outside scale
- no letter used 3 times when making outside the scale tones (2 =max=)

checking:

- vertically, sharps should read fcgdaeb
- vertically, flats  should read beadgcf
- cols should have SAME letter:  2,3  4,5  6,7  9,10  11,12

So the usual spellings work out like this:

```
==================== MAJOR KEYS ===================      ! means PLAIN cuz ksig
            xx      xx          xx      xx      xx       % means natural
flats   KEY m2  M2  m3  M3  4   tri DOM m6  M6  m7  M7   d double flat, x db shp
0       C   db  D   eb  E   F   f#  G   ab  A   bb  B
1       F   gb  G   ab  A   B!  b%  C   db  D   eb  E
2       B!  cb  C   db  D   E!  e%  F   gb  G   ab  A
3       E!  fb  F   gb  G   A!  a%  B!  cb  C   db  D
4       A!  bd  B!  cb  C   D!  d%  E!  fb  F   gb  G
5       D!  ed  E!  fb  F   G!  g%  A!  bd  B!  cb  C
6       G!  ad  A!  bd  B!  C!  c%  D!  ed  E!  fb  F    or F#
7       C!  dd  D!  ed  E!  F!  f%  G!  ad  A!  bd  B!   B in sharps preferred

            xx      xx          xx      xx      xx
sharps  KEY m2  M2  m3  M3  4   tri DOM m6  M6  m7  M7
1       G   ab  A   bb  B   C   c#  D   eb  E   f%  F!
2       D   eb  E   f%  F!  G   g#  A   bb  B   c%  C!
3       A   bb  B   c%  C!  D   d#  E   f%  F!  g%  G!
4       E   f%  F!  g%  G!  A   a#  B   c%  C!  d%  D!
5       B   c%  C!  d%  D!  E   e#  F!  g%  G!  a%  A!
6       F!  g%  G!  a%  A!  B   b#  C!  d%  D!  e%  E!   or Gb
7       C!  d%  D!  e%  E!  F!  fx  G!  a%  A!  b%  B!   Db in flats preferred

==================== MINOR KEYS ===================
            xx          xx      xx          %#      %#
flats   KEY m2  M2  m3  M3  4   tri DOM m6  M6  m7  M7
0       A   bb  B   C   c#  D   d#  E   F   f#  G   g#
1       D   eb  E   F   f#  G   g#  A   B!  b%  C   c#
2       G   ab  A   B!  b%  C   c#  D   E!  e%  F   f#
3       C   db  D   E!  e%  F   f#  G   A!  a%  B!  b%
4       F   gb  G   A!  a%  B!  b%  C   D!  d%  E!  e%
5       B!  cb  C   D!  d%  E!  e%  F   G!  g%  A!  a%
6       E!  fb  F   G!  g%  A!  a%  B!  C!  c%  D!  d%
7       A!  bd  B!  C!  c%  D!  d%  E!  F!  f%  G!  g%

            xx          xx      xx          #x      #x
sharps  KEY m2  M2  m3  M3  4   tri DOM m6  M6  m7  M7
1       E   f%  F!  G   g#  A   a#  B   C   c#  D   d#
2       B   c%  C!  D   d#  E   e#  F!  G   g#  A   a#
3       F!  g%  G!  A   a#  B   b#  C!  D   d#  E   e#
4       C!  d%  D!  E   e#  F!  fx  G!  A   a#  B   b#
5       G!  a%  A!  B   b#  C!  cx  D!  E   e#  F!  fx
6       D!  e%  E!  F!  fx  G!  gx  A!  B   b#  C!  cx
7       A!  b%  B!  C!  cx  D!  dx  E!  F!  fx  G!  gx
```

Comment: This is tablature, not note-naming.  Granted it's not completely clear, but I read the OP's question as "What is the correct nameset for G#-Major per standard harmony theory?"  in which case the answer is "G# A#, B#, C#, D##, E#, F##,G# "  Edit: apologies if you posted that -- I can't render the first image you posted.

Comment: @NReilingh Yep, the 'tablature' version has gone away. So the tables provided don't "go up" to G# Major -- maybe we should add my first comment in.  Also -- the "!" character seems to be indicating "#" or "flat" when in the "KEY" column

Comment: There seems to be a key for what ! means at the top. Also I'll note your first comment is slightly inaccurate -- no D##.

Comment: That ! is a "steve-ism", sorry.  I had to work these out all on my own, and so ! means "don't show the #/b as it's implied by the key signature".  I don't think G# is a standard key signature.  You'ld use Ab normally.

Comment: @StephenHazel - can you elucidate on your 3rd rule. It seems to be stated backwards. The major scale, Ionian mode, is the starting place for notes, not the minor.

Comment: @Tim I don't know what you mean by "the major scale is the starting point for notes"...  Are you familiar with the naming of intervals?  In C minor, m6 and m7 would be Ab and Bb while M6 and M7 would be A and B.  But they'd be spelled out in sheet music with m6 and m7 at A and B with keysig flatting them both and M6 and M7 would be naturalled

Comment: It's generally accepted that ,for example, the parallel minor has a flat 3rd, rather than the parallel major has a sharp 3rd. The datum point being from a major standpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure about this, but I remember reading about the [circle of fifths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8DPk.png) (linked) that among other things, it also shows how many sharps or flats there are in each key.
So for example if you are talking about the key of F#, it should have 6 sharp notes in it, so you would be using all the "sharp" names for the notes and not the "flat" or "regular" names.

Also, I'm pretty sure that as a general rule, you would never use a "flat name" for describing the notes in a "sharp" key scale, and vice versa.

Hope this helps, and I also hope I'm not wrong or misleading, because I'm not 100% sure about this.